# Feasibility tolerances SCIP

Tags: optimization, scip

SCIP has a parameter in which we can set the feasibility tolerance for constraints (`numerics/feastol`). Is this a relative or absolute tolerance? And if it's relative tolerance, can you please explain how it is calculate? Which norm is used etc. I tried to look at the documentation for this, but could not find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tolerances are all absolute.